# How to call functions from sprites in groups?

Tags: python, events, pygame, sprite

I have a `Sprite` class that I have but in a group. Every time the mouse button is clicked I want to call a function from the class. The function should be called for every item in the group.

I only know how to call the `update` function from every item in the group but the code would be very slow if instead of calling the function on every mouse click I would call it on every frame.

To make it more clear I'll give an example:

```
class sprite_object(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(sprite_object, self).__init__()

    def on_mouse_click(self):
        #when the mouse is clicked to some stuff
        pass

    def update(self):
        #do some stuff every frame
        pass

sprite_object_1 = sprite_object()
sprite_object_2 = sprite_object()

group_of_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

group_of_sprites.add(sprite_object_1, sprite_object_2)
```

Now, I could call the `on_mouse_click` function in the `update` function but that would make the code inefficient.

How do I call the `on_mouse_click` function from every object in the group?

Answer (score 2):

The `sprites()` method of a sprite group object returns a list of sprites this sprite group object contains.

You could iterate through this list (i.e. all sprites your sprite group `groupe_of_sprites` holds) to call the `on_mouse_click()` method of each individual `sprite_object`:

```
for sprite_object in groupe_of_sprites.sprites():
    sprite_object.on_mouse_click()
```